# What consequence deleting idb file will have on my mysql database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I tried to check what is consumming my Disk Space on Centos 7, I found these 2 database file:

> /var/lib/mysql/pub/vues.ibd: 8.1G 
>   /var/lib/mysql/pub/log.ibd: 8.6G

I would like to delete them. pub is the name of my database.
And log and vues are  tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be most unwise. Never fiddle with MySQL files directly.

If you want to delete those tables use SQL:

```
DROP TABLE pub.vues, pub.log
```

Comment: droping the table vue maybe dangerous isn't there any other way of reducing the size?....

Comment: The entire data for these tables are in those files. You could create a new table as an extract of those tables and rename the tables.

Comment: @aidonsnous - If your _real_ Question is about disk space and/or shrinking the .ibd file, then start a new Question with that as the focus.

Answer (score 2):

As @danblack pointed out it's not the best idea. However to formally answer your question - if you delete the `vues.ibd` and `log.ibd` files the InnoDB dictionary will still keep entries about them. If you ever decide to create tables with same name the `CREATE TABLE` statement will fail.